# OpenGL Hook, How to modify 3d model color?

Tags: opengl, hook, opengl-compat

Hook game is cs 1.6

Hook's glbegin function

I want to assign colors to the character model rendering, but the code is invalid

Ask for help

```
void APIENTRY hkGLBegin(GLenum mode)
{
    if (mode==5)
    {
        
        glEnable(GL_TEXTURE_2D);
        glColor4f(0, 0, 0, 0); //TODO FIXME failed
        glDisable(GL_TEXTURE_2D);
    }
}
```

Comment: It depends how the game renders character models. Do you know how the game renders character models?

Answer (score 1):

I am not familiar with this kind of GL hacking so I might be wrong... however

**What do you mean by code is invalid?** Is there any error message compile time or runtime ? Maybe you just need to add:

```cpp
#include <gl.h>
```

or

```cpp
#include <gl\gl.h>
```

or any other abbreviation related to your compiler ...

I do not think `glEnable(GL_TEXTURE_2D); glDisable(GL_TEXTURE_2D);` are allowed inside `glBegin/glEnd` ...

In case the hook is before `glBegin` then enabling and disabling texture will disable texture also if the hook does not call original `glBegin` you might want to add that too...

So I would leave just `glColor` and remove the texture statement they have nothing to do with color anyway...

If it does not work it might suggest that the CS is overiding it with own `glColor` calls or lighting has not enabled `glEnable(GL_COLOR_MATERIAL);` so try to add it ...

Why use `mode == 5` instead of `mode == GL_TRIANGLE_STRIP` ? This is taken from `gl.h`

```cpp
#define GL_POINTS                           0x0000
#define GL_LINES                            0x0001
#define GL_LINE_LOOP                        0x0002
#define GL_LINE_STRIP                       0x0003
#define GL_TRIANGLES                        0x0004
#define GL_TRIANGLE_STRIP                   0x0005
#define GL_TRIANGLE_FAN                     0x0006
#define GL_QUADS                            0x0007
#define GL_QUAD_STRIP                       0x0008
#define GL_POLYGON                          0x0009
```

Also are you sure CS is using that primitive only? if not you should also handle the others too ...

so I would change to:

```cpp
#include <gl.h> // optional if compile errors present
void APIENTRY hkGLBegin(GLenum mode)
   {
   if (mode==GL_TRIANGLE_STRIP)
      {
      glEnable(GL_COLOR_MATERIAL); // optional if color is not changed by glColor on textured surfaces
      glColor4f(0, 0, 0, 0);      
      }
   glBegin(mode); // optional if nothing is rendered
   }
```